# Opening a new window with jQuery - blocked, but still works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open a popup window when a user clicks a button on a bootstrap modal window. It seems to work just fine. Chrome spawns a new tab and shows the link, but if I click back to the original tab, it shows it blocked a popup window? I've tried this several different ways and it always seems to work, but Chrome says it is being blocked still.

Any ideas? The popup is a direct result of the user performing the action of clicking the button.

```
$('.modal-button .btn').click(function() {
var selected = $('#modal-option option:selected').val();
window.open(selected, '_blank');
$('.modal-header .close').click();
});
```

Also, will this work with all browsers without being blocked? IE seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the button to an anchor and this issue went away.